# Como fechar um dropdown caso o usuário clique em outro local da página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dropdown

Qual é o melhor método para esconder uma `div`, que está cumprindo o papel de `dropdown`, quando o usuário clicar em outro local da página?

A princípio, valorizo soluções *cross-browser* e sem a utilização de *frameworks*, mas qualquer conteúdo extra de aplicações utilizando **jQuery** ou até mesmo de **CSS** serão bem-vindas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma variação da resposta do talles, sem jQuery, para IE9+ e demais browsers modernos:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  var aEsconder = document.querySelector('[seu seletor]');
  var alvoDescendeDoAEsconder = (function(){
    var el = e.target.parentNode;
    while(el) {
      if(el === aEsconder) return true;
      el = el.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
  }());
  if (aEsconder !== e.target && !alvoDescendeDoAEsconder) 
    aEsconder.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var aEsconder = $('[seu seletor]');
  if (!aEsconder.is(e.target) && aEsconder.has(e.target).length == 0) aEsconder.hide();
});
```

([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385673/1316620))

---

Teste:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            var aEsconder = $("#conteudo1");
            if (!aEsconder.is(e.target) && aEsconder.has(e.target).length == 0) aEsconder.hide();
        });
    </script>
</head>    
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="conteudo1" style="min-height: 100px; background-color: yellow;">Se clicado aqui essa div continua sendo exibida</div>
        <div id="conteudo2" style="min-height: 100px; background-color: red;">Se clicado aqui, ou em outro lugar da página, a div acima sumirá</div>
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como o seu Drop-down vai fechar caso o usuário clique em qualquer lugar da página, você pode usar um seletor genérico para que ele seja fechado, apenas adicionando este código:

```js
    $('*').click(function(e){
         e.stopPropagation();
         if(!$(this).hasClass('.classeDoElementorAbrir')){
           $('#suaDiv').hide();
         } 
    });
```

e para que ele abra:

```js
$('btAbrir').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     $('#suaDiv').show();
});
```

Comment: O seletor `$('*')` vai casar com todos os elementos. Se você tiver 1000 elementos na página, vai rodar `$('#suaDiv').hide()` 1000 vezes – isso sem contar a propagação do evento, na verdade vai rodar bem mais...

Comment: Você se enganou, na pergunta o cara pede uma solução para fechar o drop-down quando o usuário clicar em algum elemento, portanto ele só irá executar caso o usuário clique em algum elemento da tela, justamente por isso utilizei a função [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)...

Comment: Verdade, eu me enganei, não vai rodar 1000 vezes nesse caso. Mas considere somente a parte da propagação do evento: se você clicar numa div aninhada 10 níveis pra dentro do body, o evento vai propagar e rodar 10 vezes. Além disso, com esse código um clique dentro do próprio dropdown (por exemplo, clique na seta de abrir do dropdown) causará o fechamento. Obs: não fui eu quem te votou pra baixo.

Comment: Resolvendo suas observações editei minha resposta, no caso do if para o elemento que tem que abrir o drop-down existem milhoes de formas de tratar isso...

Comment: Ok, mas você quis dizer `classeDoElementorFechar`? Eu ainda prefiro a solução com um único event handler e delegação (`$('*').click` adiciona um handler a cada elemento do html).

Comment: Depende do ponto de vista, bom, não apresentei minha resposta afirmando ser a melhor, fiz o que eu faria a princípio, ainda bem que o SO é bem democrático e permite que o dono da pergunta escolha a resposta que melhor lhe convém não é mesmo! ;)

Comment: Sim, sem dúvida! Eu só estava querendo ajudar, desculpe se pareci agressivo.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo básico de modal (http://jsfiddle.net/XepVr), que é bem simples de se entender.

Comment: Procure explicar/mostrar a solução na própria resposta (ao invés de postar apenas o *fiddle*)

Comment: Concordo, perde a usabilidade do SO...

Comment: Sua solução é muito boa, seria legal se simplificasse e detalhasse sua resposta. :)